# How can I use math with an iterator in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw vertical lines along the top of a 30° wedge. Here's what I've got right now:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
    \foreach \i in {0.5,0.55,...,1.5} {
        \draw [very thin, gray] (\i, {(\i-0.5)*tan(pi/6)} ) -- (\i,1.2);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results in a set of vertical lines that all begin at the same y position:

[image]

The lines should be getting progressively shorter and starting progressively higher though. It looks like the math section gets evaluated on the first iteration and is unchanged after that. How can I get the starting y position to increase on each iteration?

Comment: Right after posting this, I realized I had forgotten the coordinate system starts from the top left. I corrected this by subtracting the math result from 1.2 (the maximum y value of the lines) and now I can see some variation in the line length, but it looks like the coordinates evaluated with math aren't scaled with the rest of the figure.

Comment: No, the issue is that Ti*k*Z evaluates trigonometric functions by default in degrees and the tangent of `pi/6` degrees is very small. Either add `trig format=rad` to the options of the `tikzpicture` or use `tan(deg(pi/6))` or `tan(30)`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks, that was it. I assumed it only did radians when using "tand" gave an error.